# Get data from a simple form into controller

Tags: php, symfony

I created a form in the `FOSUserbundle:Profile:showcontent.html.twig` file. I want to know if a users want's to subscribe to the newsletter or not.

```
<form action="{{ path('fos_user_newsletter') }}" method="POST"
                    class="fos_user_newsletter" id="fos_user_newsletter">

                    <input type="checkbox" name="test123" value="HTML"


                         {% if user.newsletterEnabled == 1 %} checked


{% endif %} onclick="this.form.submit();"> Subscribe to Newsletter

                </form>
```

Now I would like to get the data in the controller.

```
public function subscribeNewsletterAction(Request $             
            var_dump($request->request->all());die;
        }
```

This doesn't display anything and I can't call the  `$form = $this->createFormBuilder($task)` because it's in `FOSUserBundle`.

How can I get the information if the checkbox is clicked or not? What thinking mistake am I doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be clear, if you created this form in the  `FOSUserBundle/Resources/views/Profile/show_content.html.twig` file, than it's wrong. You should not edit anything inside the `vendor` folder, as they can be overwritted by Composer.

You have to put this form into a template in the `src` directory.

You should create a simple form with Symfony to do this job.

```
// make sure you've imported the Request namespace above the class
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
// ...

public function subscribeNewsletterAction(Request $request)
{
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($defaultData)
        ->add('newsletter', 'choice', array(
            // ...
        ))
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $data = $form->getData();
    }

    // ... render the form
}
```

[Using a Form without a Class](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#using-a-form-without-a-class)

Comment: Yes the file is in the source folder. I needed to replace the createFormBuilder with:
  $form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->createBuilder()
Because the controller doesn't find createFormBuilder
How can I render now the form into an existing view? I would like to display it in the Profile:show.twig.html view? Meaning just the checkbox.

Comment: If you have the form with the bilder, it's easy to render it, at the response of your controller:
return $this->render('AcmeTaskBundle:Default:new.html.twig', array(
'form' => $form->createView()));

If you want to put it into the Profile FOSUserBundle page, you should overdefine the default page like this: 

Overriding templates:
https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_templates.md
Overriding controllers:

https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/overriding_controllers.md